# Access Control error when using twitter npm module

Tags: twitter, npm, xmlhttprequest, cors, access-control

I'm testing for a get response on a localhost, and have already verified that my Auth credentials are valid using postman. However when making get requests using the twitter npm library, the browser errors out.

(XMLHttpRequest cannot [load](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nodejs). Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.)

My current stack utilizes React.js/Gulp/Webpack

What sort of settings do I have to allow in order to get CORs data?

Answer (score 0):

[JSONP](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html) is the fallback solution for servers that restrict CORS or don't support OPTIONS calls for preflight checks.  jQuery has support for crossDomain scripting, that automatically converts to JSONP.